# Cython compilation error - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors, cython

I'm new to Cython and trying to speed up my kivy mobile game by using Cython code in critical AI module. My code goes as follows:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

 #not relevant parts

cdef np.ndarray posarr
cdef np.int poslast = 0
cdef np.int posidx = 0

def posarr_init(np.ndarray pawnpos, np.int act):
    poslast = 0
    # not relevant, but referencing poslast

 #not relevant, but including function where poslast is referenced (not assigned)

def consider_pawn(np.int x, np.int y):
    cdef np.int pact, posx, posy, resx, resy
    cdef np.int p
    cdef np.int found = 0
    #not relevant

    #in the code there is this line, posx and posy are local variables
                    posarr[poslast, posx, posy] = posarr[posidx, posx, posy]
```

Here Cython gives me this error during compilation:

```
Error compiling Cython file:

------------------------------------------------------------
...
                pact = 1
        if pact == 1:
            #pawn is active, create child position
            for posx in range(11):
                for posy in range(11):
                    posarr[poslast, posx, posy] = posarr[posidx, posx, posy]
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

position.pyx:98:34: local variable 'poslast' referenced before assignment
```

I can see that Cython compilation errors are reported in the same order that they appear in the code. My questions are:

Why does Cython consider poslast a local variable?

Why didn't it consider it a local variable in previous functions?

The generated C file is empty, it has only a message that it shouldn't be used inside. Is there a way to force Cython to leave the C code in the file even if there is a compilation error? Maybe looking into this file would help me understand the error messages (i.e. why this variable is considered local)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use the `global` statement to explicitly declare `poslast` as global in every function that writes to it.

**Long answer**

Cython follows Python binding rules: if a name is assigned *anywhere* in the function, it is assumed to be a local variable, unless you explicitly declare it global.

I guess that you perform and assignment to `poslast` after your example loop, which makes it an implicitly declared local variable (of type `object`). The loop then appears to use this yet uninitialized local.

Your `posarr_init` functions is similarly incorrect. It assigns implicitly declared local `poslast` without ever touching the global.

Comment: +1. Cython also supports `nonlocal` keyword (Python 3)